# Why is [[NSWindow animator] setFrame...] very laggy sometimes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, animation, nswindow

So, I have the following code to show my `NSWindow`:

```
[_window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]; 

[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[_window animator] setAlphaValue:1.0];
[[_window animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect([[NSApp currentEvent] window].frame.origin.x - 102, [[NSApp currentEvent] window].frame.origin.y - 238, _window.frame.size.width, _window.frame.size.height) display:YES];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

This code is called right after the user has clicked on the app's status bar icon, that's why I use the `[[NSApp currentEvent] window].frame.origin.y/x` to get the location of the status bar icon.
This code runs perfectly but, sometimes, it's very laggy and "jumpy" and I don't know why.
Any ideas about this and how to fix it?

Comment: I would check how many times this code is getting reached when you click. If you have two animations on the same property of the same object going at the same time, they could be interfering with each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NSWindow` animator uses `NSAnimation`, which means that it rapidly fires a timer to animate the frame of the window. At each frame of the animation, every view inside the window is redrawn. If you have large views with somewhat complex view hierarchies, the performance is quite bad and there's no real way to work around it.

I would recommend [JNWAnimatableWindow](https://github.com/jwilling/JNWAnimatableWindow) as a substitute for the default `NSWindow` animator, as it uses a Core Animation `CALayer` to perform animations on and therefore is much smoother.