# Core Animation, Swift: how to animate NSWindow

Tags: swift, core-animation, nswindow

I am trying to increase size of the NSWindow with Swift. (mac)

Now, I am able to do it without animation just fine, but I am not sure how to do it with animation.

A. I would be interested in code.

B. If there is a tutorial or book, if you could drop a link.

Answer (score 6):

The following code increases the height of a window by 50 pixels and decreases the y origin by the same amount. This enlarges the window towards the bottom of the screen.

```
var windowFrame = self.view.window?.frame
let oldX = windowFrame?.origin.x
let oldY = windowFrame?.origin.y
let oldWidth = windowFrame?.size.width
let oldHeight = windowFrame?.size.height
let toAdd = CGFloat(50.0)
let newY = oldY! - toAdd
let newHeight = oldHeight! + toAdd
windowFrame? = NSMakeRect(oldX!, newY, oldWidth!, newHeight)
self.view.window?.animator().setFrame(windowFrame!, display: true, animate: true)
```

You have to call the window's animator to get an animation (potential bug?). This does not produce an animation:

```
self.view.window?.animator().setFrame(windowFrame!, display: true, animate: true)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more correct to enlarge towards the top? as is the expected behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the animator proxy on `NSWindow`? That's the first thing I would try. It's not known to perform all that well, but if your window is not very complex, it might suit your needs. Here's [some Objective-C sample code (gist)](https://gist.github.com/indragiek/1397050) that *fades* a window using the animator proxy, but you could adapt it for frame resizing. Converting it to Swift should be pretty straightforward.

This response to a similar question, [Why is [[NSWindow animator] setFrame...] very laggy sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542509/why-is-nswindow-animator-setframe-very-laggy-sometimes), suggests using a library called [JNWAnimatableWindow](https://github.com/jwilling/JNWAnimatableWindow). It uses Core Animation. It's written in Objective-C, however, you could bring it into your Swift project with a bridging header.